# How to filter years in shiny leaflet in sliderbar (Interactive map)

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)

data <- function(con){
    con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="", host="localhost",
                     port = , user="",
                     password="")
    dbSendQuery(con, "SEt NAMES euckr")
    d <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from accidents")
    dbDisconnect(con)
}
```

raw data(d) have informations : accident happen place, accident happen year, accident occur number, longitude, latitude, etc...

This is ui

```
ui <- navbarPage("Interactive Map",
                 tabPanel("Map",
                          leafletOutput("m", height=800),
                          tags$style("
                                     #controls {
                                     backgropund-color: #ddd;
                                     opacity: 0.7;
                                     }
                                     #controls:hover{
                                     opacity: 1;
                                     }
                                     "),
                          absolutePanel(id = "controls",  class="panel panel-default",
                                        fixed =TRUE, draggable = TRUE, top=60, left="auto",
                                        right=20, bottom ="auto", width=250, height=450,
                                        sliderInput("year",
                                                    "years:",
                                                    min=min(d$acci_year),
                                                    max=max(d$acci_year),
                                                    value=range(d$acci_year),
                                                    step=1, sep=""))))
```

This is server

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
    filteredData <- reactive({
        d[d$acci_year >= input$year[1] & d$acci_year <= input$year[2],]
    })
    d_colour <- colorFactor("viridis", d$acci_type)
    
    output$m <- renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet(d) %>% 
            setView(lng = 126.97806, lat=37.56667, zoom=13) %>%
            addTiles() %>% 
            addCircles(lng=~d$longitude, lat=~d$latitude, color=~d_colour(d$acci_type), radius=20, 
                       popup=paste0("<br>accident place:", d$accident_address, "<br>accident year:", d$acci_year, "<br>발생건수:", d$발생건수,
                                    "<br>사상자수:", d$사상자수, "<br>사망자수:", d$사망자수,
                                    "<br>중상자수:", d$중상자수, "<br>경상자수:", d$경상자수,
                                    "<br>부상자수:", d$부상자수)) %>% 
            addLegend(position = "bottomleft",
                      title = "types of accident",
                      pal = d_colour, values = ~d$acci_type, opacity = 1)
    })
    
    d_colour <- colorFactor("viridis", d$acci_type)
    observe({
        
        leafletProxy("m", data=filteredData()) %>% 
            clearShapes() %>% 
            addCircles(lng=~d$longitude, lat=~d$latitude, color=~d_colour(d$acci_type), radius=20,
                       popup=paste0("<br>accident place:", d$accident_address, "<br>accident year:", d$acci_year, "<br>발생건수:", d$발생건수,
                                    "<br>사상자수:", d$사상자수, "<br>사망자수:", d$사망자수,
                                    "<br>중상자수:", d$중상자수, "<br>경상자수:", d$경상자수,
                                    "<br>부상자수:", d$부상자수))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I changed some variables korean into english for you !
I can't go for next step because of this function for a week..
Thanks for your answering really really much !!

Comment: when you type in console d$사고발생지 what happens?

Comment: @KmnsE2 Ah, it means column '사고발생지(accident happen place)' of  data d

Comment: My question completed : change d$ -> filteredData()$ in popup in observe !!

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE

The error persist in your code you are replacing all the points in the map for that reason your map dont change with sliderInput. you need to change `lng=~d$longitude, lat=~d$latitude,`  by:
`lng=~longitude, lat=~latitude,`  Which means that you dont want to add all the circles in your map `~d$longitude lat=~d$latitude`   but only the filtered by sliderinput `lng=~longitude lat=~latitude`.

When you filter with filteredData() you dont want all the information in d like `d$lat` for example do you only want the filtered information by the SliderInput: `~lat`.

## OLD ANSWER

The error in your code is here:

```r
 leafletProxy("m", data=filteredData()) %>% 
            clearShapes() %>% 
 addCircles(lng=~d$longt, lat=~d$lat, color=~d_colour(d$acci_type), # this line
```

you are replacing the points by the same points that created the map (d$longt and d$lat), for that reason the map dont change.

To solve this you need to placing the point by the filteredData() columns:

```
 leafletProxy("m", data=filteredData()) %>%  
      clearShapes() %>% clearMarkers()  %>% 
      addCircles(lng=~longt, lat=~lat,  #don't forget ~ to specify that the column comes from filteredData()
color=~d_colour(acci_type),
```

Here a full [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example):

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

d=data.frame(
  acci_year=c(2012,2013,2014,2015),
  longt=c(126.97806,126.97822126,125.97806,124.97806),
  lat=c(37.56667,35.56667,38.56667,37.56667),
  acci_type=c("low","high","medium","high"),
  accident_happen_place=c("word1","word2","word3","word4"),
  accident_2 =c("anotherword1","anotherword2","anotherword3","anotherword4"),
  accident_3=c("otheword1","otheword2","otheword3","otheword4"),
  accident_4 =c("example1","example2","example3","example4"),
  accident_5 =c("anotherexample1","anotherexample2","anotherexample3","anotherexample4"),
  accident_6 =c("onemoreexample1","onemoreexample2","onemoreexample3","onemoreexample4"),
  accident_7 =c("ex1","ex2","ex3","ex4"),
  accident_8 =c("2_ex1","2_ex2","2_ex3","2_ex4")
)
ui <- navbarPage("Interactive Map",
                 tabPanel("Map",
                          leafletOutput("m", height=800),
                          tags$style("
                                     #controls {
                                     backgropund-color: #ddd;
                                     opacity: 0.7;
                                     }
                                     #controls:hover{
                                     opacity: 1;
                                     }
                                     "),
                          absolutePanel(id = "controls",  class="panel panel-default",
                                        fixed =TRUE, draggable = TRUE, top=60, left="auto",
                                        right=20, bottom ="auto", width=250, height=450,
                                        sliderInput("year",
                                                    "years:",
                                                    min=min(d$acci_year),
                                                    max=max(d$acci_year),
                                                    value=2012:2019,
                                                    step=1, sep=""))))
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  filteredData <- reactive({
    d[d$acci_year >= input$year[1] & d$acci_year <= input$year[2],]
  })
  d_colour <- colorFactor("viridis", d$acci_type)
  
  output$m <- renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet(d) %>% 
      setView(lng = 126.97806, lat=37.56667, zoom=7) %>%
      addTiles() %>% 
      addCircles(lng=~d$longt, lat=~d$lat, color=~d_colour(d$acci_type), radius=20, 
                 popup=paste0("<br>사고장소:", d$accident_happen_place, "<br>accident_2:", d$accident_2, "<br>accident_3:", d$accident_3,
                              "<br>accident_4:", d$accident_4, "<br>accident_5:", d$accident_5,
                              "<br>accident_6:", d$accident_6, "<br>accident_7:", d$accident_7,
                              "<br>accident_8:", d$accident_8)) %>% 
      addLegend(position = "bottomleft",
                title = "사고유형",
                pal = d_colour, values = ~d$acci_type, opacity = 1)
    })
  
  
  d_colour <- colorFactor("viridis", d$acci_type)
  observe({
   
   
    leafletProxy("m", data=filteredData()) %>% 
      clearShapes() %>% 
      addCircles(lng=~longt, lat=~lat, color=~d_colour(acci_type), radius=20, 
                 popup=paste0("<br>사고장소:", d$accident_happen_place, "<br>발생년도:", d$accident_2, "<br>accident_3:", d$accident_3,
                              "<br>accident_4:", d$accident_4, "<br>accident_5:", d$accident_5,
                              "<br>accident_6:", d$accident_6, "<br>accident_7:", d$accident_7,
                              "<br>accident_8:", d$accident_8) ) 
  } )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You dont need to use dbGetquery twice:

```
d <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from accidents"
dbGetQuery(con,d)
```

That way is already perfect:

```
d <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from accidents")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering really !! but, I got this error : Error in addcircles: can't find function "addcircles"

Comment: replace addcircles by addCircles, R is case sensitive.

Comment: change your filteredData by mine filteredData <- reactive({
    d[d$acci_year >= input$year[1] & d$acci_year <= input$year[2],]
  }) . Works?

Comment: Ok i'll reupload !!

Comment: I reuploaded question

Comment: I see your new question but it not a regular behavior create a new post for this, you only need to click in edit in this post. just copy and paste your new question

Comment: I understand what you are saying but There is no 'longitude' and 'latitude' variable

Comment: try my old answer lng=~longt, lat=~lat. i only change to ~longitude because your new question has lng=~d$longitude, lat=~d$latitude.. You only need to erase "d$" in your code

Comment: i got this : Error in guessLatLongCols: Couldn't infer longitude/latitude columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224595/discussion-between-kmnse2-and-).